# enumerated datatypes and gcc

Tags: c, linux, enums

I have a function in which one of the function arguments is an integer. During function invocation I am passing an enumerated datatype to this function. After building using gcc, any access to the INTEGER variable inside the function causes a segmentation fault.

#### Sample code:

```
void somefun (unsigned int nState)
{
    switch (nState) // <-- Crashes on this line
    {
        //
        // functionality here ...
        //
    }
}

enum {

    UNDEFINED = -1,
    STATE_NICE,
    STATE_GREEDY
} E_STATE;

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    somefun (STATE_NICE);
}
```

Comment: Compile it with -g and -Wall and post any warnings. Also, run it in gdb to determine how exactly it is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all your answers it seems that the code is logically correct, and I need to investigate the *real* reason for the crash. I will investigate it and post it soon.

Answer (score 1):

First off, The enum is defined in main() and does not exist for somefun().  You should define the enum outside of main, although I cannot see how this is causing a crash.

After defining the enum outside of the main you should define somefun to be somefun( E_STATE nState ) and test again.

Comment: Well, no; since the argument is declared unsigned int, the function doesn't care about the enum, and since enums in C are ints, the call is simply casting an int to a uint.  no problem there.

Comment: exactly what I thought, and what I said.  But it does not hurt to show the proper way to use an enum.

Answer (score 1):

Actually runs for me:

```
bash $ cat bar.c
#include <stdio.h>

void somefun (unsigned int nState)
{
    switch (nState) // <-- Crashes on this line
    {
        //
        // functionality here ...
        //
      default:
        printf("Hello?\n");
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    enum {

        UNDEFINED = -1,
        STATE_NICE,
        STATE_GREEDY
    } E_STATE;

    somefun (STATE_NICE);
    return 0;
}
bash $ gcc -Wall bar.c -o bar
bar.c: In function 'main':
bar.c:22: warning: unused variable 'E_STATE'
bash $ ./bar
Hello?
bash $
```

Made a couple of changes, but it ran without them.  (1) added a tag in the switch just so it had something; (2) added the `#include <stdio.h>` and `printf` so I could tell that it had run; (3) added the `return 0;` to eliminate an uninteresting warning.

It did run successfully with none of the changes, it just didn't do anything visible.

So, what's the OS, what's the hardware architecture?

#### Update

The code changed while I was trying it, so here's a test of the updated version:

```
bash $ cat bar-prime.c
#include <stdio.h>

void somefun (unsigned int nState)
{
    switch (nState) // <-- Crashes on this line
    {
        //
        // functionality here ...
        //
      default:
        printf("Hello?\n");
    }
}

enum {

    UNDEFINED = -1,
    STATE_NICE,
    STATE_GREEDY
} E_STATE;


int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{

    somefun (STATE_NICE);
    return 0;
}
bash $ gcc -Wall bar-prime.c -o bar-prime && ./bar-prime
Hello?
bash $
```

Still works.  Are you getting a core file in your version?  Have you tried getting a stack trace?

Comment: Since nState is not used in the switch at all, is it optimized out. Anyway, gcc version 3.4.6-10 (Redhat), in a Pentium 4 PC.

Comment: Sounds good.  Code still works for me.  Since nState is being optimised out but isn't being accessed, why would it crash?

Answer (score 1):

I compiled and ran that code exactly (cut & paste) on my computer, using gcc version 4.2.4, with no errors or segmentation fault. I believe the problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is like specific to sun sparc hardware or similar. Please post uname -a and output of dmesg